# How to send image through XML using C#

Tags: c#

I have a image that I need to embed in XML and then retrieve the image using C#.  How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide more information about your specific scenario. It's too abstract question.

Answer (score 10):

Convert it to a `byte[]` and convert this to a Base64 datablock (using `Convert.ToBase64String()`), which you put into the xml. On the other side, you simply have to decode it with `Convert.FromBase64String()` and deal with the resulting `byte[]` the way you like.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to include binary data in XML tags; or you need to put the image somewhere else and send the link with your XML

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your image into base64 data and write in xml !

help:

[code snippet](http://arcanecode.com/2007/03/21/encoding-strings-to-base64-in-c/)

[stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957987/c-base64-encoding-decoding-with-serialization-of-objects-issue)

Answer (score 0):

embed image in xml? You mean putting image in a xml document?

See the link
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lookchanger.aspx

Comment: I think he means transferring an image via xml. ;)