# Decoding from Base64 in C#

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, base64

I created XML Document  and saved this document as

```
  XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
  XmlDeclaration dec = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
  xmlDoc.AppendChild(dec);
  XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(fullPath,Encoding.UTF8);
  writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
  xMLDoc.Save(writer);
  writer.Flush();
```

And then I have encoded this document using Base64 Encoder

The Decoder could not parse XML file.
I created the decoder myself and got this result

```
 ?<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<ClinicalDocument 
 xmlns=\"urn:hl7-org:v3\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
classCode=\"DOCCLIN\" moodCode=\"EVN\" schemaLocation=\"urn:hl7-org:v3
CDA.xsd\">\r\n  <typeId extension=\"POCD_HD000040\" root=\"2.16.840.1.113883.1.3
\" />\r\n
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.
How I have to save the XML file to avoid the issues?
Or How I have to encode to Base 64 to resolve the issue?
I am using base64 encoder to encode xml file.
I am requesting document. it is required to use base64 encoder.
I decoded myself to check where is the problem. 
The decoder is Java . They can not parse the xml file I believe because ?< in front of the document.

Comment: You haven't shown us what you're doing with the Base64 encoder. That's the relevant code...

Comment: What has this to do with base-64? Also - I'm guessing you copied that string out of the IDE yes? That isn't the actual string - it is the c# escaped version.

Comment: There is so much about your issue I can't follow. What are you using to base64 encode/decode your file?

Comment: Now that I've rushed out an answer on decoding from Base64, I'll ask the question - what are you trying to do with this? What is the objective?

Comment: Hi guys. I was trying access to the comments.I am encoding the xml file and sending this encoding file as a request.The decoder can not parse the file.they are getting error all the time when they are parsing my requests.What exactly you want to know about the code? Thank you

Comment: @Rose: How are you encoding it? We can't tell you how to decode it without knowing how you've encoded it. UTF-8, ASCII, Unicode? I'm going to assume that you used ASCII encoding, hence the `?` in front of the decoded string. You should use UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 29):

It depends on how you're encoding it, but you should use UTF-8 since the document is declared as such. Here are examples for encoding and decoding:

See Jon Skeet's answer here:
[C# base64 encoding/decoding with serialization of objects issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957987/c-base64-encoding-decoding-with-serialization-of-objects-issue)

To encode:

```
public string EncodeStringToBase64(string stringToEncode)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncode));
}
```

To decode:

```
public string DecodeStringFromBase64(string stringToDecode)
{       
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(stringToDecode));
}
```

Comment: Why have you introduced compression into the mix? Most of the code there is to do with compression...

Comment: Whoops! I wasn't paying attention to that part. It was something that I was fiddling around with. Forgot what I was doing in there.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: All better, I think... haven't tested it yet. This should work though, right?

Comment: Well, it depends on how we got to the base64 data to start with. The problem is that the OP hasn't given us any information on that front...

Answer (score 1):

One other option - could be BOM in default Utf-8 stream created by new XmlTextWriter(fullPath,Encoding.UTF8);

Consider using second constructor for UTF8 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s064f8w2.aspx that does not insert BOM into the stream.