# Encrypt and Decrypt a string to fixed length

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, cryptography

I looked into so many examples and tried several articles. But none of them solved my issue.

I want to encrypt my Primary Column Value in Database(INTEGER Value) and show it in the URL. I want my URL to be simple and readable, so I don't want lengthy encryption values. Mostly, I am looking around 5 to 7 characters in length.

Is this possible ? If so, what would be the best approach ?

[Encrypt and decrypt a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string/10366194)

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/306620/Encryption-Decryption-Function-in-Net-using-MD-Cry

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of info. What type is your column? what is the max length of the content?

Comment: The .NET framework has bunch of ciphers in the [`System.Security.Cryptography`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography\(v=vs.110\).aspx) namespace.

Comment: @Gusman I mentioned INTEGER value in caps.

Comment: Also, if that's an integer, why you need to cypher it?? Something so simple can just be XORed and then converted in a string, it will have a max length of 10 chars.

Comment: @Gusman I think it is straight forward, if I mention as INT. Same length as  INT. I clearly mentioned that I want 5 to 7 characters in length.

Comment: An INT can have different lengths, in MySQL you explicitly set it's length, so no, it's not straight.

Comment: Do you really need to "encrypt and decrypt" or will "encode and decode" be sufficient?  Is there some secret information you're trying to protect here?

Comment: @Gusman I don't want to show that Primary value to the outside users. So, I want to cypher it. Max length of that value is 6

Comment: Ok, I have one idea ,let me write it.

Comment: @JimLewis I tried encoding and decoding. but still the length is too big.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368136/decoding-from-base64-in-c-sharp/7368168#7368168

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per you requirements, your integers will have no more than 6 chars (999999) and the encoding should be max 7 chars, so a XOR of 24 bits will do it:

Beware this method is esily reversible by a bruteforce attack, but will hide the real numbers for the majority of the mortals.

First we use a three byte key (the values are just examples, take the ones you like the most:

```
byte[] theKey = new byte[]{ 34, 56, 98 };
```

Then to encode the integer we take the first three bytes (the fourth byte is not necessary as your INT will not use it, only 20 bits can store up to 1M, so the nearest byte count are three) and we XOR each one with the correpsonding byte at the key:

```
int cyphered = ((theValue & 0xff) ^ theKey[0]) | 
               ((((theValue >> 8) & 0xff) ^ theKey[1]) << 8) | 
               ((((theValue >> 16) & 0xff) ^ theKey[2]) << 16);
```

And finally, to make the URL's homogeneous you convert it to an string and pad it with zeroes:

```
string finalValue = cyphered.ToString().PadLeft(7, '0');
```

To reverse the value just XOR it again with the key:

```
int cyphered = int.Parse(theStringYouReceived);

int decyphered = ((cyphered & 0xff) ^ theKey[0]) | 
                 ((((cyphered >> 8) & 0xff) ^ theKey[1]) << 8)| 
                 ((((cyphered >> 16) & 0xff) ^ theKey[2]) << 16);
```

As I say, it's not precissely an AES256 security cipher (:D) but at least will hide the numbers from the curious.

EDIT: here is the test case, it works as expected:

```
            byte[] theKey = new byte[] { 34, 56, 98 }; 
            int theValue = 1413;

            int cyphered = ((theValue & 0xff) ^ theKey[0]) |
           ((((theValue >> 8) & 0xff) ^ theKey[1]) << 8) |
           ((((theValue >> 16) & 0xff) ^ theKey[2]) << 16);

            string finalValue = cyphered.ToString().PadLeft(7, '0');

            int scyphered = int.Parse(finalValue);

            int decyphered = ((scyphered & 0xff) ^ theKey[0]) |
                             ((((scyphered >> 8) & 0xff) ^ theKey[1]) << 8) |
                             ((((scyphered >> 16) & 0xff) ^ theKey[2]) << 16);
```

Comment: Isn't cyphered and decyphere code not the same ? Because it is not converting back to original value

Comment: It's the same and it will convert to the original value, that's the magic of XOR, A XOR B = C, A XOR C = B. let me execute the code to see if there is any error.

Comment: Yes, there is an error, I forgot to return back the displacement, let me correct it.

Comment: still there is as error, it is not converting to correct value

Comment: It works, gimme an example of the key, the int, the string you got and the value decyphered and I can check it.

Comment: The Key is same as you mentioned here. Integer value I am passing is 1413. When it cyphers, the value 0000255 but when convert back the value is 6437085

Comment: You have something wrong, the cipher pass will return 6438311, and the decipher will return 1413, executed and checked.

Comment: How can I modify the code that it generates a 6-digit cyphered int instead of 7-digit?

Answer (score 0):

You can of course roll your own, but the following library looks like it might be useful based on the info provided.

http://hashids.org/net/

Obviously consider your security requirements and whether this sufficiently meets them.